# Run Selenium tests using Cucumber and TestNG. Getting error java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: cucumber

```
package Runners;


import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/features"}, glue = {"gluecode"},tags = "@regression")
public class RunnersTestNG extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

This is my testrunner file. I have used testng.CucumberOptions and testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests instead of Runwith(Cucumber.class). I am getting the below error when I run this TestRunner file

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberOptionsProvider$TestNGCucumberOptions does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Class uuidGenerator()' of interface io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser$CucumberOptions.

My Gluecode is as below:

```
public class TestClass {

    WebDriver driver = Hooks.getDriver();

    @Given("The {string} of the web page to open")
    public void the_url_of_the_web_page_to_open(String url) {

        driver.get(url);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The Hooks file is

```
package gluecode.configuration;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Hooks {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        return driver;
    }
    @Before
    public void setup(){
        System.out.println("This will run before the scenario");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\aniru\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }

    @After
    public void printStatus(){
        System.out.println("This will run after the scenario");
    }

}
```

The pom.xml dependencies are:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <!-- This dependency is for @Runwith, @CucumberOptions and Cucumber.class  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.12.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>





        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <!-- This is the java implementation for Cucumber.
        This dependency is for running the testrunner file and for @Given, @When and @Then
          @Before and @After tags -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.grasshopper/extentreports-cucumber7-adapter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber7-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Feature file:

```
Feature: Test opening of different web pages based on URLs fetched from the excel

  @smoke
  Scenario: Test opening of different web pages based on URLs fetched from the excel
    Given The "https://www.google.com" of the web page to open

  @regression
  Scenario: Test opening of different web pages based on URLs fetched from the excel
    Given The "https://www.cricbuzz.com" of the web page to open
```

I am trying to run the test which is under @Regression tag
I am expecting the web page https://www.cricbuzz.com to open but I am getting the below error.

````
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.cucumber.testng.TestNGCucumberOptionsProvider$TestNGCucumberOptions does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Class uuidGenerator()' of interface io.cucumber.core.options.CucumberOptionsAnnotationParser$CucumberOptions.```
````

Comment: looks like the TestNG and Cucumber versions are not compatible.

Comment: I am using TestNG 7.8.0. and 
cucumber-testng 7.11.0

Comment: Your `pom.xml` is messy. I see at least 3 different versions of Cucumber used. You should use a BOM to keep them all consistent. Have a look at the skeleton project https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: This worked for me



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>7.12.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
      <version>7.12.1</version>
    </dependency>